# Copy and paste between Mac and Ubuntu using keyboard shortcuts via VMware Fusion

Tags: keyboard, vmware, virtualization, copy-paste

I use OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and have VMware Fusion 7.1.1 where Ubuntu 14.04 has been installed. Moreover, I have installed [VMware tools patches](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches).

Copy and paste between Mac and Ubuntu using keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) worked fine before. I don't know if it is because of the recent upgrade from VMware Fusion 6.x to 7.1.1 or the installation of the VMware tools patches, copy and paste does not work any more. Here are some screenshots of the settings:

[image]
[image]

Could anyone help?

Comment: It's not really about the shortcut. I'm not sure about VMware, I only know about Parallels - there should be an option somewhere like "share clipboard"

Answer (score 1):

Look under the settings for that particular VM, not the "App Preferences."  Each specific VM has it's own settings, and there are granular controls for `Host <--> Guest` sharing.

I only have Parallels, or I would post screenshots, but it is quite similar, from what I remember of previous VMWare Fusion versions that I used at my old job.

In the "Launch" screen, there should be a gear or some settings button for that specific VM.

Here it is in Parallels, FWIW.

[image: Settings button]

[image: Settings Pane]

Answer (score 0):

After a test install of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS in VMware 7.1.1/Mac OS X 10.9.5, then using the following (shortened) guide to download the latest VMware Tools and applying the patches, copy & paste with keyboard shortcuts from the Linux guest (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>) to the Mac host (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>) and the opposite direction just works.

```
1. Checkout the repository:

    $ git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git

2. Download the latest version of VMware Tools into
   the vmware-tools-patches folder which should reside in your user folder.

    $ cd vmware-tools-patches
    $ ./download-tools.sh 7.1.1

3. Untar the tarball, and apply the patches:

    $ cd vmware-tools-patches
    $ ./untar-and-patch.sh
4. Run the vmware-install.pl installer to install VMware Tools:

    $ ./compile.sh
```

My VM-settings look like this:

[image]

[image]

Inside the Ubuntu VM I use the "English (Macintosh)" or "German (Macintosh)" keyboard layout.

My advice: trash the folder "vmware-tools-folders" in your user folder (or wherever you have downloaded it previously), download the patches, download the VMware Tools, apply the patches and install the tools like described in the above guide. You **don't have to/mustn't** reinstall/install the VMware Tools from the VMware Fusion menubar -> Virtual Machine -> Reinstall VMware Tools following the above guide.

Comment: Thank you for the test... I followed your guilde to re-install the VMWare Tools, it still does not work... It is very odd...